# React: Execute function in useEffect Hook to update state. Use the state value to return component A or B

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, lifecycle

When a user arrives in this component. I want to execute two function in the useEffect hook:
- hasError (returns true if there is an error)
- hasState  (returns true if there is an state)

Based on the state i want to return a specific component. If access is false than 
If it is true than

The first time the user comes on the page it says that access if `false` when i refresh the page it is `true` Why doesn't the state update the first time?

Am I using the wrong lifecycle method?

**Component:**

```
const ContinueRouteComponent = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // const [access, setAccess] = useState(false);
    // const [error, setError] =  useState(false);


    const query = useQuery();

    //check if user has valid state
    const hasState = (stateId: string) => {
        // No state is given in the uri so no access

        if(stateId === null) {
            return false;
        }

        // You have a state in the uri but doesn't match the localstorage
        return localStorage.getItem(stateId) !== null;
    };

    const hasError = (error: string) => {
        return error !== null;
    };

    const [access, setAccess] = useState(() => hasState(query.get("state")));
    const [error, setError] =  useState(() => hasError(query.get("error")));


    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchResources());
    },[]);


    if(error){
        let errorType = query.get("error");
        let errorDescription = query.get("error_description");

        return <Redirect exact={true} to={{
            pathname: '/error',
            state: {
                error: errorType,
                description: errorDescription
            }
        }} />;
    }

    if(access){
        const retrievedStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(query.get("state")));
        localStorage.removeItem(query.get("state"));
        return <Redirect exact to={retrievedStorage} />
    } else {
        return <Redirect to="/"/>
    }
};


export default ContinueRouteComponent
```

Comment: Quite a lot wrong with this code: Where does `someValue`, `fetchResources`  and `dispatch` come from? The function `hasError` is not a dependency of the effect and the closure value `error` will be a stale closure. Adding it to the dependency of the effect will run the effect too many times, same goes for `hasState` but since it always returns true the linter will not complain about that one (my guess is that the real code is different because otherwise you can replace `hasState()` with `true`. Not sure how anyone can answer this question given the code you provided.

Comment: You can do `useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchResources());
  }, [dispatch]);
` and it'll dispatch fetchResources after first render and never again until mounted again. Assuming `useDispatch` comes from react-redux. You should configure your linter correctly though.

Comment: useDispatch comes from react-redux. What linter config do you recommend?

Comment: I didn'ty add teh dispatch to the dependency list because i read: 
When Component Mounts
Usually, you would like to use it for fetching data or adding event listeners.
To run the function once, add an empty dependency list. If there are no dependencies in it, that means it will stay the same all the time, and will not call the function again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209524/discussion-between-mux-and-hmr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## On initial render access state is false

You set the default state as false, this will be its value on the first render. Then when you trigger the effect `setAccess(hasState(someValue));` it sets up access to be true on the next render.

The change in state triggers a rerender with the new value but does not interrupt the current rendering.

You might spend more time thinking about yoursetup like, why not initialise the state with values?

```
const [access, setAccess] = useState(() => hasState(someValue));
const [error, setError] =  useState(() => hasError(someValue));
```

Comment: hasError is not added as dependency to the effect and will return stale closure `error` (error returned by `hasError` will never change). Can do `hasError = useCallback(...)` and add hasError as dependency for the effect but there are lots of other values used in the effect that seem to come out of nowhere.

Comment: You might spend more time thinking about yoursetup like, why not initialise the state with values? i am new to the lifecycle methods. -> I try to understand how they work and what is best practice with initialise.  When i try your example above it works.